# When i try to run the project it says cannot publish to the server because its missing is run time environment

Tags: java, servlets, jvm, google-cloud-platform

I tried to run my project with google cloud platform but it caused a problem and ended up in a dialog box where it says cannot publish to the server because its missing is run time environment. But i already have my jdk(1.8) and web app libraries configured.

Answer (score 0):

> > I tried to run my project with google cloud platform

That can mean any number of things. If you were using App Engine, it's likely your config files weren't correct.  Check the docs [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/runtime-java8).